# Push array to a data while looping in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using foreach loop and while getting the user information I will receive an array. The problem is I get that array outside my other array.

I have tried using array_push but it says the first parameter should be an array and if I put the array in the first parameter I get number as an output. I tried using array_merge but it says the second parameter is not an array.

```
$query = $news->getNewsGrihaLimit($offset, 10);

    if(is_array($query) || is_object($query)){

        $json = array();

        foreach($query as $question){

            $authorDetail = $writer->getAuthorById($question->id);

            $json = array(

            'news' => $question,

            'authorDetail' => $authorDetail

        );

           echo json_encode($json); 

        }


    }
```

Currently, I am getting the following as an output:

```
Array
(
    [news] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 350
            [title] => कृति चोरीमा त्रिविका प्रोफेसर !
            [story] => <p><strong>थुप्रै शैक्षिक र भौतिक समस्याबाट ग्रस्त त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालयसामु अर्को गम्भीर चुनौती आइपरेको छ&mdash; अर्काका कृति चोरेर आफ्ना नाममा किताब छपाउने तथा प्रमोसन हात पार्ने प्रोफेसर र रिडरहरूलाई कसरी पहिल्याउने र दण्डित गर्ने ?</strong></p>

<p>जियोलोजी अफ नेपाल हिमालय&nbsp; किताबको आवरण हेर्दा त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालय केन्द्रीय भूगर्भ विभागको संस्थागत प्रकाशन जस्तो लाग्छ । आवरण पृष्ठमा नै त्रिविको लोगो र सो विभागको नाम मुद्रित छ । तर लेखाइको हिसाबले हेर्ने हो भने अस्पष्टता देखिन्छ । यसमा डिपार्टमेन्ट अफ जियोलोजी, त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालय, काठमाडौं लेखिएको छ । &lsquo;सेन्ट्रल&rsquo; डिपार्टमेन्ट (केन्द्रीय विभाग) लेखिएको छैन । भूगर्भ शास्त्रको केन्द्रीय विभाग कीर्तिपुरमा छ । भूगर्भ विमाग चाहिं त्रिचन्द्र क्याम्पस, घण्टाघरमा छ । यस किताबका लेखक सह&ndash;प्राध्यापक डा. प्रकाश दास उलक त्रिचन्द्र क्याम्पसमा प्राध्यापन गर्छन् । &lsquo;त्रिविको अनुमति लिएर नै उसको लोगो प्रयोग गर्नुभएको हो ?&rsquo; भन्ने प्रश्न गर्दा डा. उलक एकछिन अकमकाए र जवाफ फर्काए&mdash; &lsquo;लोगो प्रयोग गर्न नपाउने भन्ने थाहा भएन ।&rsquo; तर एकैछिनपछि त्रिचन्द्रबाट अनुमति लिएको बताए ।</p>

<p>डा. उलकको अस्पष्ट जवाफ परीक्षण गर्न हामीले त्यही प्रश्न त्रिचन्द्र क्याम्पसका प्रमुख प्रदीपबहादुर न्यौपाने सामु राख्यौं । त्यसमा क्याम्पस प्रमुख न्यौपानेको स्पष्ट कथन थियो&mdash; &ldquo;यो किताब त्रिचन्द्र क्याम्पसको प्रकाशन होइन । लेखकको व्यक्तिगत हो । यस्तोमा लोगो नराखेकै भए राम्रो हुन्थ्यो ।&rdquo; अर्थात्, त्रिचन्द्र क्याम्पस र यसको भूगर्भ विभागले किताबमा आफ्नो नाम र विश्वविद्यालयको लोगो प्रयोग गर्ने अनुमति दिएको छैन । केन्द्रीय भूगर्भ विभाग, त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालय, कीर्तिपुरबाट पनि लेखक डा. उलकले विश्वविद्यालयको लोगो प्रयोगको स्वीकृति लिएका छैनन् । त्यहाँका विभागीय प्रमुख प्रा.डा. लालु पौडेल भन्छन्, &ldquo;लोगो प्रयोगका लागि अनुमति लिनुपर्छ । हरेक विभागको रिसर्च कमिटी हुन्छ । यो कमिटीले लेख वा कृति मूल्याङ्कन गरेर उपयुक्त देखिएमा मात्र अनुमति दिइन्छ । त्यो किताबको हकमा त्यस्तो केही भएको छैन ।&rdquo;</p>

<p>किताबको भित्री पृष्ठमा प्रकाशकको नाम रचना उलक छ, जो लेखककी श्रीमती हुन् । सन् २०१६ मा प्रकाशित यो पुस्तकमा मूल्य अंकित छैन, तर क्याम्पस नजिकैको पुस्तक पसलबाट रु.८०० मा बिक्री भइरहेको छ । लेखक उलकका अनुसार उक्त पुस्तक स्नातक तहका लागि निकालिएको हो । उनी भन्छन्, &ldquo;मैले ५०० प्रति निकालेको हुँ । अब १०० प्रति बाँकी छ ।&rdquo;</p>

<p>डा. उलकको यो किताबको विसंगत पक्ष आम मानिसलाई भ्रममा पार्ने गरी विना अनुमति त्रिविको लोगो प्रयोग गर्ने मात्र होइन । यसको विषयवस्तुको मौलिकतामा पनि गम्भीर प्रश्न उठाइएका छन् । किताबमा उल्लेख गरेका धेरै विषयवस्तु मात्रै होइन परिच्छेद, वाक्य र नक्शाहरू अरूका कृतिबाट चुपचाप लिइएका छन् । त्यसमध्ये एउटा हो&mdash; २०१५ मा विदेशी कम्पनी स्प्रिङ्गरले प्रकाशन गरेको प्रा.डा. मेघराज धितालद्वारा लेखिएको&mdash; जियोलोजी अफ द नेपाल हिमालय&nbsp; नामक किताब । यसबाट डा. उलकले थुप्रै सामग्री सारेको देखिन्छ ।</p>

<p><img alt="" src="/assets/editor/kcfinder/upload/images/shikshya_khabar_images/May15th_2019/p3.jpg" style="height:auto; width:100%" /></p>

<p>आफ्नो किताबको पाना नम्बर ३४४ मा <strong>Tallakot Formation</strong> शीर्षकमा डा. उलकले धितालको किताबको पाना नम्बर ४४७ बाट २५० भन्दा बढी शब्द हुबहु सारेका छन् । प्रा. धितालले यस सम्बन्धमा लेख्दा सम्बन्धित कृतिको सन्दर्भ र पाना नम्बर समेत खुलाएका छन् । तर डा. उलकले सार्दा भने उक्त सन्दर्भ हटाएका छन् । यस्तै पृष्ठ नम्बर १५६ को शीर्षक <strong>Balle Quartzite</strong> मा उनले प्रा. धितालको किताबको पृष्ठ नम्बर १०७ बाट ८० शब्दसम्म हुबहु सारेका छन् । डा. उलकले यो शीर्षकमा जति लेखेका छन्, सबै जानकारी धितालको किताबबाट नै लिएका छन् । यसरी सार्दा कतै वाक्य जस्ताको तस्तै सारेका छन् । कतै केही लाइन छाडेर सारेका छन् ।</p>

<p>यस्तै प्रा. धितालको किताबमा पाना नम्बर १२२ मा रहेको शीर्षक <strong>Tosh Group</strong> बाट झण्डै दुई अनुच्छेद सारेर डा. उलकले <strong>Dubring Formation</strong> शीर्षकमा लेखेका छन् । डा. उलकको यो शीर्षक पृष्ठ नम्बर १५५ मा छ । यसरी सार्दा ७० भन्दा बढी शब्दका केही वाक्य दुरुस्तै सारेका छन् । कतिपय वाक्य सार्दा चाहिं केही शब्द हटाएका छन् । प्रा. धितालको किताबबाट सार्दा कतै त वाक्य पूरा पनि भएको छैन, अपूरो छ । जस्तो पाना नं. १६४ मा उलकले<strong> &ldquo;There are also intercalated small columnar stromatolites, occupying various&rdquo;</strong> लेखेका छन् । धितालको किताबको पाना नम्बर १४० मा यही वाक्य छ&mdash;<strong>&ldquo;There are also intercalated small columnar stromatolites, occupying various stratigraphic positions&rdquo;</strong> छ ।</p>

<p>डा. उलकले एकाध नक्शा र तालिकामा बाहेक प्रा. धितालको किताबको सन्दर्भ कतै खुलाएका छैनन् । धितालको पुस्तकबाट परिच्छेदका परिच्छेद सारेका ठाउँमा ती परिच्छेदको स्रोतका बारेमा डा. उलक पूरै मौन बसेका छन् । अर्थात् प्रा.डा. धितालका वाक्य र परिच्छेदलाई उनले आफ्नै जस्तो बनाएर प्रस्तुत गरेका छन् । प्रा. धितालको किताब उल्लेख नगरी किन यसरी लाइनका लाइन सारेको भन्ने हाम्रो प्रश्नको जवाफमा डा. उलक भन्छन्, &ldquo;आफ्नो स्वार्थका लागि भन्दा मैले विद्यार्थीका लागि किताब निकालेको हुँ । हो, धेरै ठाउँमा उहाँको किताबको सन्दर्भ खुलाउन र उहाँलाई उद्धृत गर्न भुलें । यो म स्वीकार्छु र यो गल्ती अब दोस्रो संस्करणमा सच्याउँछु ।&rdquo;</p>

<p>यस सम्बन्धमा प्रा.डा. धिताल भन्छन्, &ldquo;डा. उलकले आफ्नो किताबमा मेरो मात्र होइन, अरू लेखकको सिर्जना पनि चोरी गरेका छन् । मेरो किताबबाट ३० भन्दा बढी चित्र र तालिका विना अनुमति सारेका छन् । किताब लेख्न मैले धेरै अध्ययन र मिहिनेत गरेको छु । एउटा नक्शा तयार गर्नै एक महीनाभन्दा बढी समय लागेको छ ।&rdquo; त्रिवि सेवा आयोगमा छानबिन र नियन्त्रण गर्ने बलियो संयन्त्र नभएकाले मिहिनेत नै नगरी बढुवाका लागि अरूको कृति चोरी हुने गरेको उनको भनाइ छ । प्राध्यापक डा. धिताल थप्छन्, &ldquo;बढुवाका लागि अहिले सेवा आयोगमा ८० प्रतिशतभन्दा बढी किताब यस्तै चोरी गरेर बुझइएका छन् । यस सम्बन्धमा छानबिन गर्ने बलियो संयन्त्र आयोगले बनाउनुपर्छ ।&rdquo;</p>

<p>आफ्नो कृति चोरी गरिएको सम्बन्धमा तपाईं अब के गर्नुहुन्छ त भन्दा प्रा.डा. धिताल भन्छन्, &ldquo;म केस गर्ने तयारीमा लागेको छु । आवश्यक प्रक्रिया अघि बढाउन आफ्नो प्रकाशकसँग यस सम्बन्धमा सल्लाह गरिरहेको छु ।&rdquo;</p>

<p><strong>त्रिविमा थुप्रै छन् उलकहरू !</strong></p>

<p>त्यसो त त्रिविमा अरूले लेखेका किताबबाट हुबहु सारेर आवरण पृष्ठ मात्र नयाँ बनाई पुस्तक निकाल्नेहरूमा डा. उलक मात्र छैनन् । त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालयको शिक्षा शास्त्र केन्द्रीय विभागमा कार्यरत राजनीतिशास्त्र शिक्षा विषयका प्राध्यापक डा. विदुरप्रसाद फुयालको &lsquo;राजनीतिशास्त्रको शिक्षण विधि (२०७०)&rsquo; त्यस्तै कृतिको अर्को उदाहरण हो । आफ्ना प्रकाशित कृतिहरू भनी उनी आफैंले उपलब्ध गराएको सूची लिएर खोजतलास गर्दा फुयालले करीब १८ वर्षअघि प्रकाशित विभिन्न लेखकका तीन वटा किताबबाट बेग्लाबेग्लै अंशहरू हुबहु सारेर यो किताब तयार पारेको देखिएको छ । पुस्तकको प्रकाशकमा विमला फुयाल, जोरपाटी, काठमाडौं लेखिएको छ । विमला डा. फुयालकी श्रीमती हुन् ।</p>

<p><img alt="" src="/assets/editor/kcfinder/upload/images/shikshya_khabar_images/May15th_2019/p2.jpg" style="height:auto; width:100%" /></p>

<p>शिक्षकलाई प्राप्त डा. फुयालको उक्त किताबको अधिकांश भाग विद्यार्थी पुस्तक भण्डारबाट २०५२ सालमा प्रकाशित अब्दुल कयूमको किताब राजनीतिशास्त्र शिक्षण विधि सँग जस्ताको तस्तै मेल खान्छ । पृष्ठ संख्या १४ देखि १६ र ४६ देखि १२२ सम्मको ७६ पृष्ठ उक्त किताबबाट हुबहु सारिएको छ । किताबको १३२ पृष्ठमध्ये शुरूको १३ पृष्ठ एमके पब्लिसर्स एण्ड डिष्ट्रिव्युटर्सबाट २०५२ सालमा प्रकाशित रामकुमार दाहालको किताब &lsquo;राजनीतिशास्त्र शिक्षण विधि&rsquo; बाट लिइएको छ । किताबको अर्को १३ पृष्ठ भुँडी पुराण प्रकाशनले २०६६ सालमा प्रकाशन गरेको चन्द्रबहादुर श्रेष्ठ, किरणराम रञ्जितकार र सम्झ्ना बस्न्यातले लेखेको पुस्तकबाट उतारेको देखिन्छ । बाँकी भागमा त्रिविले अभ्यास शिक्षणका निम्ति तयार पारेका पाठयोजना र कार्ययोजनाहरू समावेश छन् ।</p>

<p>यो पुस्तक प्रकाशन हुँदा डा. फुयाल ठिमी क्याम्पस, भक्तपुरमा सहप्राध्यापकका रूपमा कार्यरत थिए । त्यसको दुई वर्षपछि २०७२ मा त्रिवि सेवा आयोगको परीक्षाबाट पदोन्नति भई प्राध्यापक बनेका उनी हाल त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालयको राजनीतिशास्त्र केन्द्रीय विभागमा कार्यरत छन् । उनी विद्यावारिधि तह (पीएच्डी) का विद्यार्थीलाई पनि पढाउँछन् । उनीबाट सिर्जना चोरिएका लेखकद्वय रामकुमार र अब्दुल कयूमले यसबारे अहिलेसम्म थाहा नपाएको बताएका छन् । &ldquo;फुयाललाई पीएचडी गर्दा मैले नै पढाएको हुँ, मसँग सोध्दै नसोधी मेरो किताबबाट त्यसरी नक्कल गरेको सुन्दा दुःख लाग्यो&rdquo;, मूल पुस्तकका लेखक रामकुमार दाहालले भने । आफूसँग पनि बाँकी नभएको आफ्नो किताबको एक प्रति फुयालसँग मात्र रहेकाले त्यसको फाइदा उठाउँदै नक्कल गरेर छापेको हुनसक्ने आशंका उनले व्यक्त गरे ।</p>

<p>पुस्तक चोरी भएका अर्का लेखक अब्दुल कयूमले पनि आफ्नो किताब अनुमति विना फुयालले प्रकाशन गरेको थाहा पाउँदा आश्चर्य लागेको बताए । &ldquo;यस्ता कार्यलाई निरुत्साहित गर्न कानूनी उपचार खोज्छु&rdquo;, उनले भने ।</p>

<p>कृति चोरीको आरोप लागेका प्राध्यापक डा. विदुर फुयालले पनि भूगर्भका सहप्राध्यापक डा. उलक जस्तै आफ्नो गल्ती स्वीकारेका छन् । कार्यव्यस्तताका कारण आफैंले हेर्न नभ्याउँदा त्यस किसिमको त्रुटि भएको हुनसक्ने बताउँदै उनले शिक्षक सँग भने, &ldquo;काम गर्ने क्रममा मबाट मानवीय त्रुटि भयो होला तर यसबारे अहिले बाहिर केही नल्याइदिनुस् ।&rdquo; सिङ्गै किताब अन्य किताबहरूबाट जस्ताको तस्तै सारेर निकाल्नुपर्ने गरी त्रुटि कसरी हुन सक्छ भनी गरिएको प्रति प्रश्नमा उनको जवाफ थियो, &ldquo;तपाईं र म भेटघाट गरौं, केही लेख्नु नपर्ने गरी म सबै कुरा बताउँछु ।&rdquo;</p>

<p><img alt="" src="/assets/editor/kcfinder/upload/images/shikshya_khabar_images/May15th_2019/p1.jpg" style="height:auto; width:100%" /></p>

<p>त्रिवि सेवा आयोग खुल्दा अरूका कृति चोरेर आफ्नो सामग्री तयार गर्नेको संख्या धेरै हुने गरेको त्यहाँका प्राध्यापक तथा सहप्राध्यापकहरू बताउँछन् । तर आफ्नै साथीभाइ भएको र साँचो कुरा गर्दा अरूखाले असर पर्न सक्ला भनेर पनि उनीहरू बोल्न वा उजुरी गर्न चाहँदैनन् । त्यसैले पनि कृति मूल्यांकनका क्रममा विज्ञहरूले चोरी भएको थाहा पाएनन् वा पत्ता लगाउन सकेनन् भने चोरीकै कृतिले पनि अंक पाउने संभावना रहने एक उपप्राध्यापक बताउँछन् । अलि पुराना कृति जुन बजार वा कतै पुस्तकालयमा नभेटिने भएकाले यस्ताबाट चोरिएका सामग्री पत्ता लगाउन गाह्रो हुने उनी बताउँछन् ।</p>

<p>कृति चोरीको संभावनालाई त्रिवि सेवा आयोगका अध्यक्ष चैतन्य शर्मा पनि स्वीकार्छन् । उनी भन्छन्, &ldquo;चोरी हो कि होइन भनेर जाँच्ने कुनै सफ्टवेयर छैन । हामीले भर पर्ने विज्ञहरूमै हो ।&rdquo; अध्यक्ष शर्माका अनुसार कुनै प्रतिस्पर्धीलाई अरूले चोरीको कृति बुझएको शंका लागेमा आयोगमा त्यस्तो कृति हेर्न पाउन सक्ने प्रावधान छ । त्यस्तै नतिजा प्रकाशन भए पनि आन्तरिक प्रतियोगिताका हकमा २० दिनभित्र त्रिवि पुनरावलोकन आयोगमा छानबिनका लागि उजुरी गर्न र खुल्लाको हकमा अदालत जान सकिने व्यवस्था छ ।</p>

<p>त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालय शिक्षक नियुक्तिको सिफारिश सम्बन्धी विनियम, २०७५ अनुसार खुला तथा आन्तरिक प्रतियोगिताबाट प्राध्यापक, सहप्राध्यापक, उपप्राध्यापक हुन अनुुसन्धान तथा कृति प्रकाशनबाट पनि अंक प्राप्त हुने व्यवस्था छ । प्रतियोगितामा सम्मिलित कुनै उम्मेदवारले अंक प्राप्त गर्ने प्रयोजनका लागि आयोगमा पेश गरेको पुस्तक वा लेखभित्रको कुनै अंश अरू कसैको पूर्व प्रकाशित कुनै पुस्तक वा लेख वा कुनै पाठ्यसामग्रीसँग हुबहु मिल्न गएमा र सन्दर्भ नखुलाएमा त्यस्तो उम्मेदवारको सिफारिश रद्द हुने व्यवस्था छ । यस्तो अवस्थामा यदि कुनै उम्मेदवारको सिफारिश भई नियुक्ति बुझ्सिकेको अवस्था रहेछ भने पनि त्यस्तो नियुक्ति रद्द हुने उल्लेख छ । अध्यक्ष शर्मा भन्छन्, &ldquo;भएका प्रावधान प्रयोग गर्न सकिन्छ । कृति चोरी रोक्न सबैले चासो देखाउनुपर्छ । सबै नैतिकवान हुनुप&yen;यो ।&rdquo;</p>

<p><strong>कानूनमा के छ ?</strong></p>

<p>प्रतिलिपि अधिकार संरक्षण ऐन २०५९ ले कुनै पनि रचना वा पुस्तक कृतिलाई प्रतिलिपि अधिकारको संरक्षण प्राप्त हुने व्यवस्था गरेको छ । लेखकको अनुमति विना कसैले यस्ता बौद्धिक सम्पत्ति चोरी गरेमा दोषी व्यक्तिलाई कसुरको मात्रा अनुसार दश हजार रुपैयाँदेखि एक लाख रुपैयाँसम्म जरिवाना वा ६ महीनासम्म कैद वा दुवै सजाय हुने प्रावधान ऐनको दफा २५ मा छ । संरक्षणप्राप्त कृतिको प्रतिलिपि अधिकार कसैले एकपटक भन्दा बढी उल्लंघन गरेमा दोस्रो पटकदेखि पटकै पिच्छे २० हजार रुपैयाँदेखि दुई लाख रुपैयाँसम्म जरिवाना वा एक वर्षसम्म कैद वा दुवै सजाय हुने ऐनको व्यवस्था छ । त्यसका साथै पुनरुत्पादन गरिएका कृति जफत गरी प्रतिलिपि अधिकार प्राप्त व्यक्तिलाई परेको नोक्सानीको क्षतिपूर्ति उल्लंघनकर्ताबाट भराउने प्रावधान पनि ऐनमा छ । यस्ता मुद्दा सरकारवादी हुने र मुद्दाको अनुसन्धान र तहकिकात कम्तीमा प्रहरी निरीक्षकले गर्ने विधि ऐनमा उल्लेख छ । आफ्नो प्रतिलिपि अधिकार उल्लङ्घन भएको व्यक्तिले त्यसबारे थाहा पाएको मितिले तीन महीनाभित्र उजुरी प्रहरीलाई दिनु पर्ने गरी मुद्दाको हदम्याद तोकिएको छ ।</p>

<p><strong>२०७६ वैशाख अंकमा प्रकाशित ।</strong></p>

            [summary] => किताबको भित्री पृष्ठमा प्रकाशकको नाम रचना उलक छ, जो लेखककी श्रीमती हुन् । सन् २०१६ मा प्रकाशित यो पुस्तकमा मूल्य अंकित छैन, तर क्याम्पस नजिकैको पुस्तक पसलबाट रु.८०० मा बिक्री भइरहेको छ ।
            [archieveCategory] => website
            [status] => Active
            [image] => http://www.oxygenaltitude.com/uploads/news/News-20190515022811533.jpg
            [added_date] => जेठ १, २०७६
            [news_category] => शिक्षा खबर
        )

    [authorDetail] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 7
                    [author] => रोशना सुब्बा
                    [user_info] => 
                    [profile_picture] => http://oxygenaltitude.com/uploads/users/Users-20190426051029729.jpg
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 188
                    [author] => एकल सिलवाल
                    [user_info] => 
                    [profile_picture] => 
                )

        )

)
```

My expected answer would be like the following:

```
Array
(
    [news] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 350
            [title] => कृति चोरीमा त्रिविका प्रोफेसर !
            [story] => <p><strong>थुप्रै शैक्षिक र भौतिक समस्याबाट ग्रस्त त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालयसामु अर्को गम्भीर चुनौती आइपरेको छ&mdash; अर्काका कृति चोरेर आफ्ना नाममा किताब छपाउने तथा प्रमोसन हात पार्ने प्रोफेसर र रिडरहरूलाई कसरी पहिल्याउने र दण्डित गर्ने ?</strong></p>

<p>जियोलोजी अफ नेपाल हिमालय&nbsp; किताबको आवरण हेर्दा त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालय केन्द्रीय भूगर्भ विभागको संस्थागत प्रकाशन जस्तो लाग्छ । आवरण पृष्ठमा नै त्रिविको लोगो र सो विभागको नाम मुद्रित छ । तर लेखाइको हिसाबले हेर्ने हो भने अस्पष्टता देखिन्छ । यसमा डिपार्टमेन्ट अफ जियोलोजी, त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालय, काठमाडौं लेखिएको छ । &lsquo;सेन्ट्रल&rsquo; डिपार्टमेन्ट (केन्द्रीय विभाग) लेखिएको छैन । भूगर्भ शास्त्रको केन्द्रीय विभाग कीर्तिपुरमा छ । भूगर्भ विमाग चाहिं त्रिचन्द्र क्याम्पस, घण्टाघरमा छ । यस किताबका लेखक सह&ndash;प्राध्यापक डा. प्रकाश दास उलक त्रिचन्द्र क्याम्पसमा प्राध्यापन गर्छन् । &lsquo;त्रिविको अनुमति लिएर नै उसको लोगो प्रयोग गर्नुभएको हो ?&rsquo; भन्ने प्रश्न गर्दा डा. उलक एकछिन अकमकाए र जवाफ फर्काए&mdash; &lsquo;लोगो प्रयोग गर्न नपाउने भन्ने थाहा भएन ।&rsquo; तर एकैछिनपछि त्रिचन्द्रबाट अनुमति लिएको बताए ।</p>

<p>डा. उलकको अस्पष्ट जवाफ परीक्षण गर्न हामीले त्यही प्रश्न त्रिचन्द्र क्याम्पसका प्रमुख प्रदीपबहादुर न्यौपाने सामु राख्यौं । त्यसमा क्याम्पस प्रमुख न्यौपानेको स्पष्ट कथन थियो&mdash; &ldquo;यो किताब त्रिचन्द्र क्याम्पसको प्रकाशन होइन । लेखकको व्यक्तिगत हो । यस्तोमा लोगो नराखेकै भए राम्रो हुन्थ्यो ।&rdquo; अर्थात्, त्रिचन्द्र क्याम्पस र यसको भूगर्भ विभागले किताबमा आफ्नो नाम र विश्वविद्यालयको लोगो प्रयोग गर्ने अनुमति दिएको छैन । केन्द्रीय भूगर्भ विभाग, त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालय, कीर्तिपुरबाट पनि लेखक डा. उलकले विश्वविद्यालयको लोगो प्रयोगको स्वीकृति लिएका छैनन् । त्यहाँका विभागीय प्रमुख प्रा.डा. लालु पौडेल भन्छन्, &ldquo;लोगो प्रयोगका लागि अनुमति लिनुपर्छ । हरेक विभागको रिसर्च कमिटी हुन्छ । यो कमिटीले लेख वा कृति मूल्याङ्कन गरेर उपयुक्त देखिएमा मात्र अनुमति दिइन्छ । त्यो किताबको हकमा त्यस्तो केही भएको छैन ।&rdquo;</p>

<p>किताबको भित्री पृष्ठमा प्रकाशकको नाम रचना उलक छ, जो लेखककी श्रीमती हुन् । सन् २०१६ मा प्रकाशित यो पुस्तकमा मूल्य अंकित छैन, तर क्याम्पस नजिकैको पुस्तक पसलबाट रु.८०० मा बिक्री भइरहेको छ । लेखक उलकका अनुसार उक्त पुस्तक स्नातक तहका लागि निकालिएको हो । उनी भन्छन्, &ldquo;मैले ५०० प्रति निकालेको हुँ । अब १०० प्रति बाँकी छ ।&rdquo;</p>

<p>डा. उलकको यो किताबको विसंगत पक्ष आम मानिसलाई भ्रममा पार्ने गरी विना अनुमति त्रिविको लोगो प्रयोग गर्ने मात्र होइन । यसको विषयवस्तुको मौलिकतामा पनि गम्भीर प्रश्न उठाइएका छन् । किताबमा उल्लेख गरेका धेरै विषयवस्तु मात्रै होइन परिच्छेद, वाक्य र नक्शाहरू अरूका कृतिबाट चुपचाप लिइएका छन् । त्यसमध्ये एउटा हो&mdash; २०१५ मा विदेशी कम्पनी स्प्रिङ्गरले प्रकाशन गरेको प्रा.डा. मेघराज धितालद्वारा लेखिएको&mdash; जियोलोजी अफ द नेपाल हिमालय&nbsp; नामक किताब । यसबाट डा. उलकले थुप्रै सामग्री सारेको देखिन्छ ।</p>

<p><img alt="" src="/assets/editor/kcfinder/upload/images/shikshya_khabar_images/May15th_2019/p3.jpg" style="height:auto; width:100%" /></p>

<p>आफ्नो किताबको पाना नम्बर ३४४ मा <strong>Tallakot Formation</strong> शीर्षकमा डा. उलकले धितालको किताबको पाना नम्बर ४४७ बाट २५० भन्दा बढी शब्द हुबहु सारेका छन् । प्रा. धितालले यस सम्बन्धमा लेख्दा सम्बन्धित कृतिको सन्दर्भ र पाना नम्बर समेत खुलाएका छन् । तर डा. उलकले सार्दा भने उक्त सन्दर्भ हटाएका छन् । यस्तै पृष्ठ नम्बर १५६ को शीर्षक <strong>Balle Quartzite</strong> मा उनले प्रा. धितालको किताबको पृष्ठ नम्बर १०७ बाट ८० शब्दसम्म हुबहु सारेका छन् । डा. उलकले यो शीर्षकमा जति लेखेका छन्, सबै जानकारी धितालको किताबबाट नै लिएका छन् । यसरी सार्दा कतै वाक्य जस्ताको तस्तै सारेका छन् । कतै केही लाइन छाडेर सारेका छन् ।</p>

<p>यस्तै प्रा. धितालको किताबमा पाना नम्बर १२२ मा रहेको शीर्षक <strong>Tosh Group</strong> बाट झण्डै दुई अनुच्छेद सारेर डा. उलकले <strong>Dubring Formation</strong> शीर्षकमा लेखेका छन् । डा. उलकको यो शीर्षक पृष्ठ नम्बर १५५ मा छ । यसरी सार्दा ७० भन्दा बढी शब्दका केही वाक्य दुरुस्तै सारेका छन् । कतिपय वाक्य सार्दा चाहिं केही शब्द हटाएका छन् । प्रा. धितालको किताबबाट सार्दा कतै त वाक्य पूरा पनि भएको छैन, अपूरो छ । जस्तो पाना नं. १६४ मा उलकले<strong> &ldquo;There are also intercalated small columnar stromatolites, occupying various&rdquo;</strong> लेखेका छन् । धितालको किताबको पाना नम्बर १४० मा यही वाक्य छ&mdash;<strong>&ldquo;There are also intercalated small columnar stromatolites, occupying various stratigraphic positions&rdquo;</strong> छ ।</p>

<p>डा. उलकले एकाध नक्शा र तालिकामा बाहेक प्रा. धितालको किताबको सन्दर्भ कतै खुलाएका छैनन् । धितालको पुस्तकबाट परिच्छेदका परिच्छेद सारेका ठाउँमा ती परिच्छेदको स्रोतका बारेमा डा. उलक पूरै मौन बसेका छन् । अर्थात् प्रा.डा. धितालका वाक्य र परिच्छेदलाई उनले आफ्नै जस्तो बनाएर प्रस्तुत गरेका छन् । प्रा. धितालको किताब उल्लेख नगरी किन यसरी लाइनका लाइन सारेको भन्ने हाम्रो प्रश्नको जवाफमा डा. उलक भन्छन्, &ldquo;आफ्नो स्वार्थका लागि भन्दा मैले विद्यार्थीका लागि किताब निकालेको हुँ । हो, धेरै ठाउँमा उहाँको किताबको सन्दर्भ खुलाउन र उहाँलाई उद्धृत गर्न भुलें । यो म स्वीकार्छु र यो गल्ती अब दोस्रो संस्करणमा सच्याउँछु ।&rdquo;</p>

<p>यस सम्बन्धमा प्रा.डा. धिताल भन्छन्, &ldquo;डा. उलकले आफ्नो किताबमा मेरो मात्र होइन, अरू लेखकको सिर्जना पनि चोरी गरेका छन् । मेरो किताबबाट ३० भन्दा बढी चित्र र तालिका विना अनुमति सारेका छन् । किताब लेख्न मैले धेरै अध्ययन र मिहिनेत गरेको छु । एउटा नक्शा तयार गर्नै एक महीनाभन्दा बढी समय लागेको छ ।&rdquo; त्रिवि सेवा आयोगमा छानबिन र नियन्त्रण गर्ने बलियो संयन्त्र नभएकाले मिहिनेत नै नगरी बढुवाका लागि अरूको कृति चोरी हुने गरेको उनको भनाइ छ । प्राध्यापक डा. धिताल थप्छन्, &ldquo;बढुवाका लागि अहिले सेवा आयोगमा ८० प्रतिशतभन्दा बढी किताब यस्तै चोरी गरेर बुझइएका छन् । यस सम्बन्धमा छानबिन गर्ने बलियो संयन्त्र आयोगले बनाउनुपर्छ ।&rdquo;</p>

<p>आफ्नो कृति चोरी गरिएको सम्बन्धमा तपाईं अब के गर्नुहुन्छ त भन्दा प्रा.डा. धिताल भन्छन्, &ldquo;म केस गर्ने तयारीमा लागेको छु । आवश्यक प्रक्रिया अघि बढाउन आफ्नो प्रकाशकसँग यस सम्बन्धमा सल्लाह गरिरहेको छु ।&rdquo;</p>

<p><strong>त्रिविमा थुप्रै छन् उलकहरू !</strong></p>

<p>त्यसो त त्रिविमा अरूले लेखेका किताबबाट हुबहु सारेर आवरण पृष्ठ मात्र नयाँ बनाई पुस्तक निकाल्नेहरूमा डा. उलक मात्र छैनन् । त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालयको शिक्षा शास्त्र केन्द्रीय विभागमा कार्यरत राजनीतिशास्त्र शिक्षा विषयका प्राध्यापक डा. विदुरप्रसाद फुयालको &lsquo;राजनीतिशास्त्रको शिक्षण विधि (२०७०)&rsquo; त्यस्तै कृतिको अर्को उदाहरण हो । आफ्ना प्रकाशित कृतिहरू भनी उनी आफैंले उपलब्ध गराएको सूची लिएर खोजतलास गर्दा फुयालले करीब १८ वर्षअघि प्रकाशित विभिन्न लेखकका तीन वटा किताबबाट बेग्लाबेग्लै अंशहरू हुबहु सारेर यो किताब तयार पारेको देखिएको छ । पुस्तकको प्रकाशकमा विमला फुयाल, जोरपाटी, काठमाडौं लेखिएको छ । विमला डा. फुयालकी श्रीमती हुन् ।</p>

<p><img alt="" src="/assets/editor/kcfinder/upload/images/shikshya_khabar_images/May15th_2019/p2.jpg" style="height:auto; width:100%" /></p>

<p>शिक्षकलाई प्राप्त डा. फुयालको उक्त किताबको अधिकांश भाग विद्यार्थी पुस्तक भण्डारबाट २०५२ सालमा प्रकाशित अब्दुल कयूमको किताब राजनीतिशास्त्र शिक्षण विधि सँग जस्ताको तस्तै मेल खान्छ । पृष्ठ संख्या १४ देखि १६ र ४६ देखि १२२ सम्मको ७६ पृष्ठ उक्त किताबबाट हुबहु सारिएको छ । किताबको १३२ पृष्ठमध्ये शुरूको १३ पृष्ठ एमके पब्लिसर्स एण्ड डिष्ट्रिव्युटर्सबाट २०५२ सालमा प्रकाशित रामकुमार दाहालको किताब &lsquo;राजनीतिशास्त्र शिक्षण विधि&rsquo; बाट लिइएको छ । किताबको अर्को १३ पृष्ठ भुँडी पुराण प्रकाशनले २०६६ सालमा प्रकाशन गरेको चन्द्रबहादुर श्रेष्ठ, किरणराम रञ्जितकार र सम्झ्ना बस्न्यातले लेखेको पुस्तकबाट उतारेको देखिन्छ । बाँकी भागमा त्रिविले अभ्यास शिक्षणका निम्ति तयार पारेका पाठयोजना र कार्ययोजनाहरू समावेश छन् ।</p>

<p>यो पुस्तक प्रकाशन हुँदा डा. फुयाल ठिमी क्याम्पस, भक्तपुरमा सहप्राध्यापकका रूपमा कार्यरत थिए । त्यसको दुई वर्षपछि २०७२ मा त्रिवि सेवा आयोगको परीक्षाबाट पदोन्नति भई प्राध्यापक बनेका उनी हाल त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालयको राजनीतिशास्त्र केन्द्रीय विभागमा कार्यरत छन् । उनी विद्यावारिधि तह (पीएच्डी) का विद्यार्थीलाई पनि पढाउँछन् । उनीबाट सिर्जना चोरिएका लेखकद्वय रामकुमार र अब्दुल कयूमले यसबारे अहिलेसम्म थाहा नपाएको बताएका छन् । &ldquo;फुयाललाई पीएचडी गर्दा मैले नै पढाएको हुँ, मसँग सोध्दै नसोधी मेरो किताबबाट त्यसरी नक्कल गरेको सुन्दा दुःख लाग्यो&rdquo;, मूल पुस्तकका लेखक रामकुमार दाहालले भने । आफूसँग पनि बाँकी नभएको आफ्नो किताबको एक प्रति फुयालसँग मात्र रहेकाले त्यसको फाइदा उठाउँदै नक्कल गरेर छापेको हुनसक्ने आशंका उनले व्यक्त गरे ।</p>

<p>पुस्तक चोरी भएका अर्का लेखक अब्दुल कयूमले पनि आफ्नो किताब अनुमति विना फुयालले प्रकाशन गरेको थाहा पाउँदा आश्चर्य लागेको बताए । &ldquo;यस्ता कार्यलाई निरुत्साहित गर्न कानूनी उपचार खोज्छु&rdquo;, उनले भने ।</p>

<p>कृति चोरीको आरोप लागेका प्राध्यापक डा. विदुर फुयालले पनि भूगर्भका सहप्राध्यापक डा. उलक जस्तै आफ्नो गल्ती स्वीकारेका छन् । कार्यव्यस्तताका कारण आफैंले हेर्न नभ्याउँदा त्यस किसिमको त्रुटि भएको हुनसक्ने बताउँदै उनले शिक्षक सँग भने, &ldquo;काम गर्ने क्रममा मबाट मानवीय त्रुटि भयो होला तर यसबारे अहिले बाहिर केही नल्याइदिनुस् ।&rdquo; सिङ्गै किताब अन्य किताबहरूबाट जस्ताको तस्तै सारेर निकाल्नुपर्ने गरी त्रुटि कसरी हुन सक्छ भनी गरिएको प्रति प्रश्नमा उनको जवाफ थियो, &ldquo;तपाईं र म भेटघाट गरौं, केही लेख्नु नपर्ने गरी म सबै कुरा बताउँछु ।&rdquo;</p>

<p><img alt="" src="/assets/editor/kcfinder/upload/images/shikshya_khabar_images/May15th_2019/p1.jpg" style="height:auto; width:100%" /></p>

<p>त्रिवि सेवा आयोग खुल्दा अरूका कृति चोरेर आफ्नो सामग्री तयार गर्नेको संख्या धेरै हुने गरेको त्यहाँका प्राध्यापक तथा सहप्राध्यापकहरू बताउँछन् । तर आफ्नै साथीभाइ भएको र साँचो कुरा गर्दा अरूखाले असर पर्न सक्ला भनेर पनि उनीहरू बोल्न वा उजुरी गर्न चाहँदैनन् । त्यसैले पनि कृति मूल्यांकनका क्रममा विज्ञहरूले चोरी भएको थाहा पाएनन् वा पत्ता लगाउन सकेनन् भने चोरीकै कृतिले पनि अंक पाउने संभावना रहने एक उपप्राध्यापक बताउँछन् । अलि पुराना कृति जुन बजार वा कतै पुस्तकालयमा नभेटिने भएकाले यस्ताबाट चोरिएका सामग्री पत्ता लगाउन गाह्रो हुने उनी बताउँछन् ।</p>

<p>कृति चोरीको संभावनालाई त्रिवि सेवा आयोगका अध्यक्ष चैतन्य शर्मा पनि स्वीकार्छन् । उनी भन्छन्, &ldquo;चोरी हो कि होइन भनेर जाँच्ने कुनै सफ्टवेयर छैन । हामीले भर पर्ने विज्ञहरूमै हो ।&rdquo; अध्यक्ष शर्माका अनुसार कुनै प्रतिस्पर्धीलाई अरूले चोरीको कृति बुझएको शंका लागेमा आयोगमा त्यस्तो कृति हेर्न पाउन सक्ने प्रावधान छ । त्यस्तै नतिजा प्रकाशन भए पनि आन्तरिक प्रतियोगिताका हकमा २० दिनभित्र त्रिवि पुनरावलोकन आयोगमा छानबिनका लागि उजुरी गर्न र खुल्लाको हकमा अदालत जान सकिने व्यवस्था छ ।</p>

<p>त्रिभुवन विश्वविद्यालय शिक्षक नियुक्तिको सिफारिश सम्बन्धी विनियम, २०७५ अनुसार खुला तथा आन्तरिक प्रतियोगिताबाट प्राध्यापक, सहप्राध्यापक, उपप्राध्यापक हुन अनुुसन्धान तथा कृति प्रकाशनबाट पनि अंक प्राप्त हुने व्यवस्था छ । प्रतियोगितामा सम्मिलित कुनै उम्मेदवारले अंक प्राप्त गर्ने प्रयोजनका लागि आयोगमा पेश गरेको पुस्तक वा लेखभित्रको कुनै अंश अरू कसैको पूर्व प्रकाशित कुनै पुस्तक वा लेख वा कुनै पाठ्यसामग्रीसँग हुबहु मिल्न गएमा र सन्दर्भ नखुलाएमा त्यस्तो उम्मेदवारको सिफारिश रद्द हुने व्यवस्था छ । यस्तो अवस्थामा यदि कुनै उम्मेदवारको सिफारिश भई नियुक्ति बुझ्सिकेको अवस्था रहेछ भने पनि त्यस्तो नियुक्ति रद्द हुने उल्लेख छ । अध्यक्ष शर्मा भन्छन्, &ldquo;भएका प्रावधान प्रयोग गर्न सकिन्छ । कृति चोरी रोक्न सबैले चासो देखाउनुपर्छ । सबै नैतिकवान हुनुप&yen;यो ।&rdquo;</p>

<p><strong>कानूनमा के छ ?</strong></p>

<p>प्रतिलिपि अधिकार संरक्षण ऐन २०५९ ले कुनै पनि रचना वा पुस्तक कृतिलाई प्रतिलिपि अधिकारको संरक्षण प्राप्त हुने व्यवस्था गरेको छ । लेखकको अनुमति विना कसैले यस्ता बौद्धिक सम्पत्ति चोरी गरेमा दोषी व्यक्तिलाई कसुरको मात्रा अनुसार दश हजार रुपैयाँदेखि एक लाख रुपैयाँसम्म जरिवाना वा ६ महीनासम्म कैद वा दुवै सजाय हुने प्रावधान ऐनको दफा २५ मा छ । संरक्षणप्राप्त कृतिको प्रतिलिपि अधिकार कसैले एकपटक भन्दा बढी उल्लंघन गरेमा दोस्रो पटकदेखि पटकै पिच्छे २० हजार रुपैयाँदेखि दुई लाख रुपैयाँसम्म जरिवाना वा एक वर्षसम्म कैद वा दुवै सजाय हुने ऐनको व्यवस्था छ । त्यसका साथै पुनरुत्पादन गरिएका कृति जफत गरी प्रतिलिपि अधिकार प्राप्त व्यक्तिलाई परेको नोक्सानीको क्षतिपूर्ति उल्लंघनकर्ताबाट भराउने प्रावधान पनि ऐनमा छ । यस्ता मुद्दा सरकारवादी हुने र मुद्दाको अनुसन्धान र तहकिकात कम्तीमा प्रहरी निरीक्षकले गर्ने विधि ऐनमा उल्लेख छ । आफ्नो प्रतिलिपि अधिकार उल्लङ्घन भएको व्यक्तिले त्यसबारे थाहा पाएको मितिले तीन महीनाभित्र उजुरी प्रहरीलाई दिनु पर्ने गरी मुद्दाको हदम्याद तोकिएको छ ।</p>

<p><strong>२०७६ वैशाख अंकमा प्रकाशित ।</strong></p>

            [summary] => किताबको भित्री पृष्ठमा प्रकाशकको नाम रचना उलक छ, जो लेखककी श्रीमती हुन् । सन् २०१६ मा प्रकाशित यो पुस्तकमा मूल्य अंकित छैन, तर क्याम्पस नजिकैको पुस्तक पसलबाट रु.८०० मा बिक्री भइरहेको छ ।
            [archieveCategory] => website
            [status] => Active
            [image] => http://www.oxygenaltitude.com/uploads/news/News-20190515022811533.jpg
            [added_date] => जेठ १, २०७६
            [news_category] => शिक्षा खबर
            [authorDetail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [user_id] => 7
                            [author] => रोशना सुब्बा
                            [user_info] => 
                            [profile_picture] => http://oxygenaltitude.com/uploads/users/Users-20190426051029729.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [user_id] => 188
                            [author] => एकल सिलवाल
                            [user_info] => 
                            [profile_picture] => 
                        )

                )
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the author details as a property of the `$question` object. Also, you need to push the value into an array so that you get all the results, rather than overwriting it on each pass through the loop. Change:

```
$json = array(
              'news' => $question,
              'authorDetail' => $authorDetail
             );
```

to

```
$question->authorDetail = $authorDetail;
$json[] = array('news' => $question);
```

Comment: It says argument 1 is not n array.

Comment: @LennaSmith I've edited my code. It should match your desired results now.

Comment: Hi @LennaSmith what is (was?) the problem?

Comment: I was facing some kind of syntax error which has been solved. I appreciate for your concern.

Comment: @LennaSmith No worries. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't something to do with the answer.